# How to make database table for following

Tags: mysql, database

One database problem is as follows:- Many users have many authorities these authorities are module wise (i.e. sales & distribution module, material management module, etc) these modules have varius Screens & buttons if he select module he will be able to see only those Screen with that related module... but if he is CEO of company then he shoud have access to all module. How to make database tables for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a database related problem.
You can do this with authorization.

See the following links for more help.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/user-based-authorization-cs

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98950/ASP-NET-authentication-and-authorization